# How to extract the key & value from this particular string?

Tags: php

I have the following string:

```
address=test&address2=test2&email=a@a.com
```

How can I extract the keys (**address**, **address2**, **email**) and values ("**test**", "**test2**", "**a@a.com**")

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `parse_str()` http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 0):

since this is just a string I would use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with delimiters as '&' and then '=', not a great idea but works

Comment: This particular example is, however real data may include encoded characters (with `+` and `%..` having special significance).